# create truth table of subfunctions based on main function truth table

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates

I have a question about the below truth table and logic functions.

I need to create the truth tables of the subfunctions based on the information given. There is no information on which gates are being used so i am not sure how to construct the truth tables.

$$\begin{array}{|cccc|c|cccc|c|}
a & b & c & d & H & a & b & c & d & H\\ \hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
\end{array}$$

[image]

Comment: @BrianDrummond - G and F are shown in the lower diagram. Inputs are along the bottom and output H is at the top.

Comment: Ah. The little block that doesn't open into an image. Oh wait, it just did at last. I'll delete my comments, but I'll note that the info would have been better in text. That diagram also contains a very obvious hint : "e".

Answer (score 3):

I think it's a poor problem to begin with, because it's not very clear what the overall purpose is and is generally not uniquely solvable as BlueSky has pointed out.

$$\begin{array}{ccc|ccc|ccl}
a & b & c & e & c & d & H    & &   \\ \hline\hline
0 & 0 & 0 &   & 0 & 0 & 0    & &   \\
0 & 0 & 0 &   & 0 & 1 & 0    & &   \\
0 & 0 & 1 &   & 1 & 0 & 0    & & ⬅  \\
0 & 0 & 1 &   & 1 & 1 & 1    & &   \\
0 & 1 & 0 &   & 0 & 0 & 0    & &   \\
0 & 1 & 0 &   & 0 & 1 & 0    & &   \\
0 & 1 & 1 &   & 1 & 0 & 1    & &   \\
0 & 1 & 1 &   & 1 & 1 & 1    & &   \\
1 & 0 & 0 &   & 0 & 0 & 0    & &   \\
1 & 0 & 0 &   & 0 & 1 & 1    & & ⬅  \\
1 & 0 & 1 &   & 1 & 0 & 1    & &   \\
1 & 0 & 1 &   & 1 & 1 & 1    & &   \\
1 & 1 & 0 &   & 0 & 0 & 0    & &   \\
1 & 1 & 0 &   & 0 & 1 & 0    & &   \\
1 & 1 & 1 &   & 1 & 0 & 1    & &   \\
1 & 1 & 1 &   & 1 & 1 & 1    & &   \\
\end{array}$$

This is both truth tables side by side, i.e. left-hand side $$e = G(a,b,c)$$ and right-hand side $$H = F(e,c,d)$$

Now, it's immediately obvious that `F` couldn't be a simple gate, i.e. not a 3-input `and`, `or`, `nand`, `nor`, `xor`, `not xor (biconditional)`, because some lines where `H = 1` contain zeros, e.g. line 7.

Now, looking at the table some more, most of the time, `H = F(e,c,d) = c`. In fact, only two lines don't show this behavior, which I marked with ⬅.

Now, the marked lines appear only once with `not c` and every where else they're `c`. This means the difference must be in the `e` input to `F` in those lines, i.e. `e` must be `1` for both groups of lines and `0` for all others or vice versa. The choice of which lines have `e = 1` and which have `e = 0` is arbitrary, hence the solution to this problem is not unique.
Notice that groups of two lines share the same `e`, because the inputs to `e = G(a,b,c)` are the same.

$$\begin{array}{ccc|ccc|ccl}
a & b & c & e & c & d & H    & &   \\ \hline\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0    & &   \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0    & &   \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0    & & ⬅  \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1    & &   \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0    & &   \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0    & &   \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1    & &   \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1    & &   \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0    & &   \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1    & & ⬅  \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1    & &   \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1    & &   \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0    & &   \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0    & &   \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1    & &   \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1    & &   \\
\end{array}$$

Thus, we have tagged the "special" lines with `e = 1` and all "regular" lines with `e = 0`, thus

$$\text{Regular lines:}\quad\quad \overline{e}c \quad\quad \text{Our observation that for most lines $H = c$}$$
$$\text{Line 4:}\quad\quad ecd \quad\quad \text{First tagged group, second line.}$$
$$\text{Line 10:}\quad\quad e\overline{c}d \quad\quad \text{Second tagged group, first line.}$$

Therefore, we can write `F` as $$ F(e,c,d) = \bar{e}c \vee ecd \vee e\bar{c}d$$ With the truth table for `F` (right hand side of table) done, we can read `G` as $$G(a,b,c) = \overline{a} \overline{b}c \vee a\overline{b} \overline{c}$$

Problem solved. I reiterate that I think it's a poor question/problem, because both gates are in fact not "obvious" simple logic gates. Still, I hope you could take away something from my solution to this problem.

Comment: thanks for your your answer, I had to read through quite a few times but I got it after a while. I have a question though, I have a similar question and I tried this method on it. In this question there was no clear similarity between the c,d lines and the H line, meaning about half ended up being regular lines and half not. This also meant their wasnt really a clear equation for the regular lines since it was mixed. Can this method be used in all instances or just in this case ?

Comment: @dmnte The "regular line" case was just a shortcut. You can construct a disjunctive normal form (or conjunctive normal form) from any truth table. IMO K-map and an unintuitive truth table make it hard to reduce the terms. A lot depends on "just seeing" an appropriate solution that covers most cases and choose e wisely.

Comment: I think there is a small mistake in the final formula for G. It should be \$G(a,b,c) = \overline{a}\overline{b}c \vee a\overline{b}\overline{c}\$.

Comment: Fixed, thanks. Apparently, the nice looks of the single overline got to me ;)

Answer (score 1):

I am not inclined to fully solve this problem for you because then you would likely learn little from the exercise. But I would start by first constructing a K-Map for the overall H function and writing out the logic equation for the minimal representation of H as a function of a, b, c, and d. You can then start to factor the resulting expression to arrive at sub functions that may produce an independent part of the expression that is a function of a, b, and c to produce the e term.

Answer (score 0):

It is mathematically impossible to calculate the sub-functions of a known functions just having the truth table of the function.

if:

$$h(a,b,c,d)=f(g(x),c,d)$$

And if you don't know one of the sub-functions, you can't calculate the other function.

In your case you only know h(a,b,c,d) . thus, you can't know what its sub-functions are.

Comment: This is what the question says exactly. " Let $H(a,b,c,d)$ be a logic function whose truth table is shown below. Consider that $H$ is composed of other subfunctions $G(a,b,c)$ and $F(c,d,e)$ as shown in the figure. Show the truth tables of $F$ and $G$.

This is a past exam question so it would be preety funny if its not possible to do.

Comment: @dmnte you say they are not known to be logic gates. so we can't.